# Formatting issue in the suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, timestamps

I just noticed this in the suggested edits queue:

[image: Um...]

For some reason, the time of asking/proposal is pushed to the other side of the username. This isn't particularly important, I just thought I'd bring it to the dev's attention.

Browser: Chrome 28, on Linux Mint KDE x86-64.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Are you in the suggested edits queue? It only shows up there.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Cool. I guess you're not an SE dev though. Maybe post that as an answer and they'll implement it?

Comment: I'm not sure how the bug reports work, but do you think that this will get more attention from the devs if you don't accept the answer just yet?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Yes. Sorry that I had to make you lose 15 rep just now. ;)

Comment: Not a problem. I'd rather see it fixed. :)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Thanks. Now all we need are fourty sock puppet accounts to up vote the proposal... ;)

Comment: @sha, that's a duplicate of my question :-(.

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor CSS difference between nameplates in the suggested edit queue and elsewhere:

```
.answer-summary .relativetime { float: right; ...}
```

Removing the float appears to fix the problem.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

A [friendly unicorn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard) informed me that the float is necessary for the timestamp on individual answers displayed on the user profile Answers tab. A possible fix is to add the float only for that location:

```
.user-answers .answer-summary .relativetime { float: right; ...}
```

Comment: For the record, that float was added when the timestamps were added to the answers tab in user profile page.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, I can see why it is useful there.

Comment: Yup. Problem is that as far as I can tell as programmer, behind the scenes both locations are using the same View so separating them isn't that easy to do.